# sqlite table last row duplicates when passing values to arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am trying to pass `sqlite` table values to an `arraylist`. The values of `sqlite` table shows correctly but when they are passed to `arraylist`.the last row duplicates the number of rows in `sqlite` table which means if the `sqlite` table is having 2 rows I am getting 2 indexes in `arraylist` but only the value of last inserted row duplicates again and again.please help me

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            roleTableModel.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID)));
            Log.d("Role id", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID))));
            roleTableModel.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME)));
            Log.d("Role Name", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME))));
            roleTableModel.setValue(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT)));
            Log.d("Role Value", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT))));
            roleDetails.add(roleTableModel);
```

Comment: Could you post your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time in `loop` you need to create new instance of `RoleTableModel` as in

```
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    roleTableModel = new RoleTableModel();//<--add this line
 roleTableModel.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID)));
                    Log.d("Role id", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID))));
                    roleTableModel.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME)));
                    Log.d("Role Name", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME))));
                    roleTableModel.setValue(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT)));
                    Log.d("Role Value", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT))));
                    roleDetails.add(roleTableModel);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...I was so much occupied with this issue.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code : Put `while (cursor.moveToNext());` at last of your code.

> while (cursor.moveToNext()); will stop if there will no next value available in the
>   table

```
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RoleModel roleTableModel = new RoleModel(); //Create object every time
                roleTableModel.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID)));
                Log.d("Role id", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID))));
                roleTableModel.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME)));
                Log.d("Role Name", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME))));
                roleTableModel.setValue(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT)));
                Log.d("Role Value", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT))));
                roleDetails.add(roleTableModel);

               } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                    Log.e("Total/Count List Size", "" + cList.size()); //ArrayList Size
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this below code where `cursor.moveToNext()` executes to new row.

You are defining values to the same object so it adds same object reference.

Create each time new object in while loop as stated below.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

    RoleModel roleTableModel = new RoleModel();

     roleTableModel.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID)));
        Log.d("Role id", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ID))));
        roleTableModel.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME)));
        Log.d("Role Name", String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_NAME))));
        roleTableModel.setValue(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT)));
        Log.d("Role Value", String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoleTableModel.ROLE_COUNT))));
        roleDetails.add(roleTableModel);

    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```